# Using HTML code to detect image size on screen

Tags: node.js, image-compression, sharp

I'm developing an app that grabs the HTML from a webpage and looks at images, within the HTML, that can be compressed and resized.

I can do the first part no problem in node, using Sharp here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

I can, of course, resize the same image here too. I just don't know what dimensions to use. I don't want a tiny image to scale up and so on.

Can I somehow detect the size of the image on screen using the HTML I got to begin with?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for any confusion. I need to know how big the image is being displayed on the page. So, the image may be 400x400 but the css could limit it to 200x200.

If I have a large image (1000x1000) but it's only being shown on screen at 500x500, I'd know it's a great candidate for resizing.

I'm just not sure how I can resize based on it's css dimensions.

Comment: You should use: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Answer (score 1):

I think in Sharp there's a [metadata](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-input/#metadata) function that lets you access image metadata, e.g. format, width, height, etc.

Example:

```
const image = sharp(inputJpg);

image.metadata().then(function(metadata) {
    // print image width and height
    console.log({
        width: metadata.width,
        height: metadata.height
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Are you aware of anything that helps with my edit above? Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you want to get the rendered image dimensions from the actual live webpage, or from the HTML source code that you've grabbed?

Comment: It's much easier if you do it from the actual live webpage because you can just use `img.clientWidth` and `img.clientHeight` on the image element to detect its rendered dimensions ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)). It might be more difficult to do it from the source code because some images might have dynamic dimensions - for example if someone used `width: 50%` then the image size would change depending on the browser window size.

Comment: Thanks, Horace. Makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

In Sharp library,

You can get dimension from this document:
http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/search.html?q=dimension

Hope it will help you.

```
const sharpImage = sharp('test/test.jpg');
image.metadata().then(function(metadata) {
    console.log(metadata);
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20485425)

Comment: Edited my answer @eisbehr